# center.x and center.y with array of uiimageviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I created an `NSMutableArray` of `UIImageView` like this:

```
NSMutableArray* imageViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    UIImageView* imageView = [self animationInit:imageArray xPos:0 yPos:480 wFrame:32
                                                      hFrame:32 duration:0.5 repeat:0];
    [imageViewArray addObject:imageView];
    [imageView release];
    imageView = nil;
    [self.view addSubview:[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

The method "animationInit" is a method I created to init the UIImageView. Its implementation is this:

```
-(UIImageView*)animationInit:(NSArray*)imageArray xPos:(float)x yPos:(float)y wFrame:
                    (float)w hFrame:(float)h duration:(float)duration repeat:(float)count {
     UIImageView* imageAnimation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
     imageAnimation.animationImages = imageArray;
     imageAnimation.animationDuration = duration;
     imageAnimation.animationRepeatCount = count;

     return imageAnimation;
 }
```

I am able to set the center of each UIImageView in the array using like this:

```
[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index] setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];
```

Now I would like to do be able to modify the `x` and `y` points like I would with a normal `UIImageView`. An example: `UIImageView.center = CGPointMake(UIImageView.center.x + 5, UIImageView.center.y + 5);`

The problem here is I have no idea how to access the "UIImageView.center.x/y" within the array of `UIImageViews`. Is there any way to access the "center.x/y" like I was able to with "setCenter:" or would I be better off creating a bunch of `CGPoints` to hold the `x` and `y` of the `UIImageViews` in the array?

When I try `[imageViewArray objectAtInded:Index].center.x`, I get the following error.

> Request for member 'center' in something no a structure or union

Is there a solution or workaround?

Comment: You can loop through the image views in the array and change their center property. What's the problem you have with that?

Comment: sorry i guess im not so good at explaining things what i want to do is something like this: [[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index] setCenter:CGPointMake([imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index].x + 5, [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index].y + 5])]; but obviously this is not possible the way i have written it. does this make more sense now?

Comment: You can do it like that? Why do you say that it is not possible?

Comment: i can't believe i didn't catch that. i just answered my own question without realizing it. i figure since i had use "setCenter" that i would need to access the x and y points the same way. so i was looking for a solution that resemble [[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index] setCenter:] syntax that i didn't think to try the "." syntax. i feel like such a fool. regardless, thanks for taking the time to look over my question and give me your input.

Comment: ok i was wrong/right, but just realize what was the problem with using [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index].center.x. when i try to use it this way i get the following error: "request for member 'center' in something not a structure or union". so that was why i was looking for an alternative. sorry for the confusing, i will edit my original question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the `x` and `y` values of an array of `UIImageViews` you have to use the following.

```
[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index] center].x
```

With that, I was able to use the following.

```
UIImageView.center = CGPointMake(UIImageView.center.x + 5, UIImageView.center.y + 5);
```

Like this:

```
[[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index] setCenter:CGPointMake([imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index] center].x + 5, [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:Index] center].y + 5)];
```

Again sorry for the mess and any confusion I may have caused. I confused the heck out of myself with this one.

(I found the solution and thought it best I share it just in case anyone else runs into the same problem.)